# Vba count rows and return number of rows to a message box

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel. I have a search button and lets assume i searched and got 3 records found.

What I want to know is: how to display the number of records found in a message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work?

```
Sub Msg_exe()  
result = MsgBox("Found values:", yourValue)
End Sub
```

you just need to pass your variable to the textbox function :)

For counting the rows, there are several ways of how you can do it:

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: do i need to do a count of rows?

Comment: "and lets assume i searched and got 3 records found"......"What i want to know is how do i display the number of records found to a message box" this was the answer to the question or am I wrong?
Downvoters any comment?

Comment: its kind of a vague answer.

Comment: im having some compile error(variable not defined) on this line : Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)